# Parallel resonance with two difference frequencies

Tags: resonance

[image]

This is an old tutorial question. In this problem, circuit has two different frequencies. My question is how to find resonance frequency? Can we consider this two different frequency as half power frequencies? but =2−1 and 1/ so B = 10 rad/s. but frequencies difference are 500 rad/s.

please give some advice. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that this problem is missing information? (Imagine L=0. Does any of the information provided invalidate that?)

Comment: The circuit doesn't have 2 different frequencies; only the generator has. The resonant frequency could be either of those, or something else altogether.

Comment: @jonk L is about 2mH, see if I did it right, below there in my answer. It is interesting to revisit paper and pencil,, believe me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: f = 1 / (2PIsqrt(LC))]

What mixture of AC currents you're feeding into the RLC circuit makes no difference to the resonant frequency. The RLC circuit will just result in some amplitudes and phases across the "feed port", for your frequencies of interest.

My math knowledge lacks a lot, but let me hazard a guess: V = Z * I , where all three are complex numbers, dependent on frequency :-)

That simple formula for resonant frequency applies, unless you assign some "internal impedance" values (a combination of RLC) to the ideal current source :-) Ahem... so much for common sense and a bit of tongue in cheek.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the input current source.

Evaluate Z-Thevenin = R // sL // (1/ sC)

Find s1 and s2 such that Z-Thevenin goes to infinity.

Set the denominator to zero and solve the polynomial second-order equation.

Comment: For what range of values of s1,s2 do you expect Z-thevenin to exceed R?

Answer (score 0):

Well, many part agree with Enrico. It is a simple algebra, if I haven't forgotten too much.

> Z = R//SL//(1/SC). => R.LS / (R.LS.CS + R + LS) -- (1)
> , might be incorrect, you need to run the expansion again. 
> v = i * Z --(2) 
> R = 200 --(3.1) 
> C = 500uF --(3.2) 
> i1 = 1 @ S = 1000 --(4) 
> i2 = A @ S = 1500 --(5) 
> i = i1 + i2 --(6)

Thus,.. now you can calculate, I will let you finish the homework.

---

Edited, if this was what you were upset about,

> My question is how to find resonance frequency?

[Resonance frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit) never change. It is the property of the circuitry, but not of the excitation. Impedance, thus the response to the excitation, changes upon the excitation, which is the definition of the resonance in a way.

Comment: Yah, I expected something wrong with my answer. :-) Thanks, sincerely, for '-1'. Could someone kindly give me a frank advice? In far distance, I thought, I used to exchange S with 2.pi.f or W. And the rest looked like superposition. I may need to go back to book at the first chance.